# Error while inserting products after deleting store view in magento 2

Tags: magento, magento2

I installed a themeforest layout using the demo package. All worked fine.
This demo has some store views for example. I deleted all store fronts that I will not need and the frontend worked fine!

The problem is:
When I try to insert a new product I'm receiving this error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`loja_magento`.`catalog_product_website`, CONSTRAINT `CATALOG_PRODUCT_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID_STORE_WEBSITE_WEBSITE_ID` FOREIGN KEY (`website_id`) REFERENCES `store_website` (`website_id`) ON DELET), query was: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_website` (`product_id`,`website_id`) VALUES (?, ?)
```

I have no idea how to fix it. Someone can help me?

**Magento 2.4**

Comment: I am having this issue as well in Single Store mode after migrating from M1.